# Adding two columns in Dask with apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a Dask function that adds a column to an existing Dask dataframe, this works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'height':  [6.21, 5.12, 5.85, 5.78, 5.98],
    'weight': [150, 126, 133, 164, 203]
})

df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2) 


s = """
obj.weight + 100
"""

df_dask['new_weight'] = df_dask.apply(lambda obj: eval(s), meta=dict, axis=1)
```

Now, I want to add two columns instead of one:

```
s = """
obj.weight + 100, obj.weight + 200
"""

df_dask['new_weight','new_weight2'] = df_dask.apply(lambda obj: eval(s), meta=dict, axis=1)
```

But I get

```
NotImplementedError: Item assignment with <class 'tuple'> not supported
```

Does this mean that this is not supported or I'm doing something wrong? If not supported, is there a workaround? What I need is to return a list of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it will be useful to make sure that the `pandas`-based solution delivers the expected result:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'height':  [6.21, 5.12, 5.85, 5.78, 5.98],
    'weight': [150, 126, 133, 164, 203]
})

s = """
obj.weight + 100, obj.weight + 200
"""

df['new_weight'], df['new_weight2'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda obj: eval(s), axis=1))

print(df)
#    height  weight  new_weight  new_weight2
# 0    6.21     150       250.0        350.0
# 1    5.12     126       226.0        326.0
# 2    5.85     133       233.0        333.0
# 3    5.78     164       264.0        364.0
# 4    5.98     203       303.0        403.0
```

Now, for the `dask` solution. Since each partition is a `pandas` dataframe, the easiest solution (for row-based transformations) is to wrap the `pandas` code into a function and plug it into `map_partitions`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'height':  [6.21, 5.12, 5.85, 5.78, 5.98],
    'weight': [150, 126, 133, 164, 203]
})

s = """
obj.weight + 100, obj.weight + 200
"""

df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2) 

def new_cols(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['new_weight'], df['new_weight2'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda obj: eval(s), axis=1))
    return df

df_dask = df_dask.map_partitions(new_cols)

print(df_dask.compute())
#    height  weight  new_weight  new_weight2
# 0    6.21     150       250.0        350.0
# 1    5.12     126       226.0        326.0
# 2    5.85     133       233.0        333.0
# 3    5.78     164       264.0        364.0
# 4    5.98     203       303.0        403.0
```

The above pattern might have scope for efficiency improvement depending on the specifics of your use case.

Comment: Sultan, in my case the `apply` fails because the `meta` is not defined. Assuming that all the types return are floats, what would be the related `meta`? `Metadata inference failed in new_cols. You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to determine the type of output that that function returns. To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword. `

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot know without seeing your actual code. Meta should be a zero or one-row dataframe with the same structure as the output of `apply`. Note that @SultanOrazbayev's solution does *not* use Dask apply.

Comment: Could you explain (a) why you are using a copy when you enter the `new_cols` function and (b) why you go through an `eval` for your lambda expression?